# Collapse with column and index in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am looking to do a particular operation on a pandas `DataFrame`using python3. I want to collapse a *NxK* `DataFrame` into a *NKx3* `DataFrame` which consists of three columns: the entry, the column and the index from the original `DataFrame`. Here is an example:

```
          'a' 'b' 'c'
    'e'    1   2   3
    'f'    4   5   6
```

Desired output:

```
         0   1   2
    0    1  'a' 'e'
    1    4  'a' 'f'
    2    2  'b' 'e'
    3    5  'b' 'f'
    4    3  'c' 'e'
    5    6  'c' 'f'
```

I am looking for a pythonic elegant way to achieve this, but as I am dealing with very large dataframes, the highest priority is efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `pandas`

use `unstack` + `reset_index`

```
df.unstack().reset_index()

  level_0 level_1  0
0       a       e  1
1       a       f  4
2       b       e  2
3       b       f  5
4       c       e  3
5       c       f  6
```

---

replicate exactly what you have

```
df.unstack().rename_axis([1, 2]).reset_index().sort_index(1)

   0  1  2
0  1  a  e
1  4  a  f
2  2  b  e
3  5  b  f
4  3  c  e
5  6  c  f
```

## `numpy`

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame({
        0: v.ravel('F'),
        1: df.columns.values.repeat(v.shape[0]),
        2: np.tile(df.index.values, v.shape[1])
    })

   0  1  2
0  1  a  e
1  4  a  f
2  2  b  e
3  5  b  f
4  3  c  e
5  6  c  f
```